# VSTS Extension Error : Extension operation denied by event callback. Found

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, marketplace, azure-devops-extensions

We have published new version of our VSTS extension to visualstudio marketplace.We have fully tested and make sure extension works fine prior to publish. And now when I am trying to install it from marketplace, following error appears, which makes no seance of what went wrong. any clue on this?

Extension operation denied by event callback. Found

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems this error is occurring due to some (hidden) issue from microsoft marketplace. we were able to contact them (VSMarketplace@microsoft.com) and get this resolved